# Trying to add User32.lib to linker instead of using #pragma comment (lib, "User32.lib")

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker, directx

Im using Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7 32bit.

I was doing the tutorial at http://www.directxtutorial.com/Lesson.aspx?lessonid=9-4-1 in Visual Studio 2010 to learn DirectX.

To VC++ Directories > Include Directories, I added: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft DirectX SDK (August 2009)\Include;"

TO VC++ Directories > Libirary Directories C:\Program Files\Microsoft DirectX SDK (August 2009)\Lib\x86;

Under Properties Manager > Properties > Properties >Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies, I added: User32.lib;d3d9.lib;d3dx9.lib;

They are now:

```
    full include directories: C:\Program Files\Microsoft DirectX SDK (August 2009)\Include;$(VCInstallDir)include;$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\include;$(WindowsSdkDir)include;$(FrameworkSDKDir)\include;

    full library directories: C:\Program Files\Microsoft DirectX SDK (August 2009)\Lib\x86;$(VCInstallDir)lib;$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\lib;$(WindowsSdkDir)lib;$(FrameworkSDKDir)\lib

additional depdendencies: User32.lib;d3d9.lib;d3dx9.lib;kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib;comdlg32.lib;advapi32.lib;shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib;uuid.lib;odbc32.lib;odbccp32.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)
```

I did that because i wanted the relevent libaries accessable by the linker in the linker settings.

My problem is this that unless I add:

```
    #pragma comment (lib, "User32.lib")
```

to the top of my c++ code like this:

```
    // include the basic windows header files and the Direct3D header file
    #include 
    #include 
    #include 

    // include the Direct3D Library file
    //#pragma comment (lib, "d3d9.lib")//i commented out this
    #pragma comment (lib, "User32.lib")//I ADDED THIS


    // global declarations
    LPDIRECT3D9 d3d;    // the pointer to our Direct3D interface
    LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 d3ddev;    // the pointer to the device class

    // function prototypes
    void initD3D(HWND hWnd);    // sets up and initializes Direct3D
    void render_frame(void);    // renders a single frame
    void cleanD3D(void);    // closes Direct3D and releases memory

    // the WindowProc function prototype
    LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);


    // the entry point for any Windows program
    int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                       HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                       LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                       int nCmdShow)
    {
        HWND hWnd;
        WNDCLASSEX wc;

        ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

        wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
        wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
        wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
        wc.hInstance = hInstance;
        wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
        wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
        wc.lpszClassName = "WindowClass";

        RegisterClassEx(&wc);

        hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
                              "WindowClass",
                              "Our First Direct3D Program",
                              WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                              300, 300,
                              800, 600,
                              NULL,
                              NULL,
                              hInstance,
                              NULL);

        ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

        // set up and initialize Direct3D
        initD3D(hWnd);

        // enter the main loop:

        MSG msg;

        while(TRUE)
        {
            while(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }

            if(msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                break;

            render_frame();
        }

        // clean up DirectX and COM
        cleanD3D();

        return msg.wParam;
    }


    // this is the main message handler for the program
    LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        switch(message)
        {
            case WM_DESTROY:
                {
                    PostQuitMessage(0);
                    return 0;
                } break;
        }

        return DefWindowProc (hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }


    // this function initializes and prepares Direct3D for use
    void initD3D(HWND hWnd)
    {
        d3d = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);    // create the Direct3D interface

        D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;    // create a struct to hold various device information

        ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp));    // clear out the struct for use
        d3dpp.Windowed = TRUE;    // program windowed, not fullscreen
        d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;    // discard old frames
        d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = hWnd;    // set the window to be used by Direct3D


        // create a device class using this information and the info from the d3dpp stuct
        d3d->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,
                          D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
                          hWnd,
                          D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,
                          &d3dpp,
                          &d3ddev);
    }


    // this is the function used to render a single frame
    void render_frame(void)
    {
        // clear the window to a deep blue
        d3ddev->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 40, 100), 1.0f, 0);

        d3ddev->BeginScene();    // begins the 3D scene

        // do 3D rendering on the back buffer here

        d3ddev->EndScene();    // ends the 3D scene

        d3ddev->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);   // displays the created frame on the screen
    }


    // this is the function that cleans up Direct3D and COM
    void cleanD3D(void)
    {
        d3ddev->Release();    // close and release the 3D device
        d3d->Release();    // close and release Direct3D
    }
```

I get these linker errors:

```
    1>Source1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__DispatchMessageA@4 referenced in function _WinMain@16
    1>Source1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__TranslateMessage@4 referenced in function _WinMain@16
    1>Source1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PeekMessageA@20 referenced in function _WinMain@16
    1>Source1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ShowWindow@8 referenced in function _WinMain@16
    1>Source1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__CreateWindowExA@48 referenced in function _WinMain@16
    1>Source1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__RegisterClassExA@4 referenced in function _WinMain@16
    1>Source1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__LoadCursorA@8 referenced in function _WinMain@16
    1>Source1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__DefWindowProcA@16 referenced in function "long __stdcall WindowProc(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" (?WindowProc@@YGJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z)
    1>Source1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PostQuitMessage@4 referenced in function "long __stdcall WindowProc(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" (?WindowProc@@YGJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z)
    1>C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Direct3dDemo\Debug\Direct3dDemo.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 9 unresolved externals
```

Even though i have User32.lib in the linker

How can I stop using "#pragma comment (lib, "User32.lib")" and rely on the linker?

Comment: To clarify: you are editing things in the "Property Manager", not in the properties of the project in the "Solution Explorer"?

Comment: My changes to the linker are made by modifying the properties of "Properties.props" accessed via the Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like perhaps your project is missing the property sheet `Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user`. When creating a new Windows Application solution, this should be added to your list of property sheets automatically, and the linker settings there should include user32.lib. Inspect the list of property sheets included in your project in the Property Manager (View->Property Manager). If this is not listed, add it (it is located in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\MSBuild\v4.0`), or you could simply create a new project and it should be added automatically.

Then when you are in Visual Studio, go to the solution explorer (View->Solution Explorer), right click on your project and choose 'Properties' (the last in the list). This brings up the Property Page for your project, under the Linker->Input, ensure that the it includes `%(AdditionalDependencies)`. If you click on the dropdown and Edit..., ensure that user32.lib is somewhere in the 'Inhereited values' list.

If you have somehow modified a property sheet that is intended to be shared across all Visual Studio projects, you will need to either repair it manually, or, reinstall Visual Studio.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2008, this property sheet was missing due to the presence of the `UseOfMFC="1"` attribute within the vcproj file.  After removing that attribute, the build worked as expected.